# Where to store xml static string in .net core webapi project

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, static-files

I have several XML strings which are used as API queries.
I would like to store them in a static file in my .NET Core webapi project.
Trying to store them in the appsettings.json with commas as seperators or with '+', between lines caused the "Could not parse the JSON file" error, in the startup of the app.
Where can I store the XML string ? I would like them to be in a static files so I can control and see them also after deploy.
Here is an example for my XML string:

```xml
<fetch mapping="logical" distinct="true">
  <entity name="xxx">
    <attribute name="yyyy" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: `Where can I store the XML string ?` Why not store it as a xml file directly and read data from that file within your api action?

Comment: @FeiHan - This is also an option. What is the best practice for location the XML file and reaching it, using the running assembly details ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store it as a xml file directly under a folder within your Web API project, to access it from controller action, you can try:

*Inject `IWebHostEnvironment` into the constructor of your controller*

```
private IWebHostEnvironment _env;

public ValuesController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    _env = env;
}
```

*In controller action*

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var filepath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, @"XmlFiles\" + "test.xml");

    //code logic here

    return Ok();
}
```

*The structure of project may look like this*

[image]